# Which version of WindowsAzure.Storage is supported by Azure Storage Emulator 4.3?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I recently updated Windows Azure Storage nuget version to 7.1.2 and later on I've discovered that I cannot use Azure Storage Emulator anymore (It gives 400 bad request with a code which works on cloud). Its version is 4.3. I want to check which versions of AzureStorage are supported by this emulator. However I couldn't find it. So is this documented on somewhere? What are the supported versions by 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use version 7.0 of Storage Client Library if you're using Version 4.3 of the Storage Emulator.

From the [`storage emulator documentation page`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/):

> Version 4.3
>
> The storage emulator now supports version 2015-07-08 of the storage
>   services on Blob, Queue, and Table service endpoints.

Looking at [`Protocol Version Support for .NET Client Library Versions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn744252.aspx), version 7.0 of Storage Client Library supports this REST API version.